# how to avoid building blocks onto cell fracture?

Tags: mesh, add-on, rigid-body-simulation

I'm breaking a sphere and using the cell_fracture add-on to break into pieces but when fracturing:

[image: building blocks]

buiding blocks don't dissapear...

How to avoid these blocks to remain after the simulation?

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

Applying scale and rotation <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> don't solve the problem..

[image: problem not solved]

Comment: If you mean that you'd like to make sphere continue being sphere after fractured then try [applying scale](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/reset_object_transformations.html?highlight=apply%20transforms#apply-object-transformations) via `Ctrl`+`A` menu. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation

Comment: it didn't solve the problem.. but I found out why this was happening: normals! The affects the 'breaking side' ;)

Comment: It solved problem for me. Applying scale (which in case of this sphere is negative) flipped normals and set scale to 1. After recalculating them I got correct fractures. This allowed normals of sphere to be pointing correctly (outside).

Comment: You are illuminating me..! I missed the  negative scale! After all.. they are synonymous I suppose :)

Comment: I'd say the scale > normals > fractures are cause and consequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normals influence the breaking side.

Flipping normals to the inside <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> solves the problem!

(in edit-mode before launching the cell-fracture add-on)

[image: problem solved]